# Loading and querying a Spark machine learning model outside of Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm currently working on a project where we're building a data pipeline. We have spark setup and have generated models. Sadly, loading the model in Spark and querying it isn't fast enough for us. What's the most straightforward way of exporting a model and loading it into memory on a local server? I've researched PMML and some libraries and that appears to be one path.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! What software exactly do you want to be running on your local server to read the model?

Comment: @Emre, Thanks for the welcome. I have a "decision" server written in pure Java that I'd like to load the model into and query. I'm not opposed to using any libraries, so long as the model can be loaded by and run in the JVM.

Comment: Obviously you need a machine learning library that can read your model parameters. I have no practical experience with them, but there's a good chance [DL4J](http://deeplearning4j.org/image-data-pipeline.html#record) and maybe [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water) will do what you want. What kind of machine learning models are you considering?

Comment: If I may ask, what do you mean by "exporting a model and loading it". How do you actually perform your export ?

Comment: @eliasah, It may be that my understanding of how machine learning models work. From working with the data-scientist on our team, I've come under the impression that once a model is trained, you can export that model to a framework-independent format.

Am I incorrect in thinking that a model can be thought of as a mathematical function? (Takes an input to its predict method, returns output.) If training the model is simply refining a mathematical function, what prevents that function from being evaluated in a different language?

Comment: The only export available now is the PMML format and I'm not sure it's the case for all the algorithms. But still what you are trying to do isn't very clear to me. How do you load your model, technically ? Are you re-training the same algorithm each time ?

Comment: @eliasah, loading the model is what I'm trying to figure out. I understand how to load a model into a Spark context and query it. That scenario shares similarities with querying a database service. What I'm trying to do is load a model into native Java data structures so the query time can be much faster.

Comment: I don't think DL4J or H2O would be relevant here. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If PMML supports the model you're trying to express, it's probably the best option. Spark has some partial support for exporting as PMML. Look into JPMML + OpenScoring to score the PMML in an embedded instance.

There are loads of tools in this space that implement something like this, but they're typically entwined with their own formats or model management system.